# $\varepsilon$ neighbourhood theorem clarification

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I am little confused about visualizing $\varepsilon$ neighborhood theorem. Here is the statement of the theorem:

Let $X$ be a compact subspace of $\Bbb R^n$; let $U$ be an open set of $\Bbb R^n$ containing $X$. Then there is an $\varepsilon>0$ such that the $\varepsilon$ neighborhood of $X$ is contained in $U$.

My confusion is this: is $\varepsilon$ neighborhood of the set $X$ an open set or closed set? I know that any neighborhood is an open set. But since $X$ is compact, it contains all its boundary, so I guess, the neighborhood should also fall into the closed set $X$. So, the neighborhood is closed. Can someone please elaborate this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be open, however it may be not closed. For example, let $X=[0,1]^n$ and $U=(-1,2)^n$ and $\epsilon=\frac12$. Then the $\frac12$ neighbourhood of $X$ is $(-\frac12,\frac32)^n$.

Comment: Can the set be both open and closed then?

Answer (score 0):

The $\varepsilon$ neighbourhood of $X$ is the set:

$$\bigcup_{x \in X} B(x, \varepsilon)$$

And since it is a union of open balls, it is open. (Observe that this is open for any set $X$)

For the proof, consider the distance between $X$ and $U^c$. That will help.

Answer (score 0):

$X$ is a compact subspace, meaning it has the topology generated by taking the intersection of $X$ with open sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. While $X$ is compact, meaning (at least in $\mathbb{R}^n$) that it is bounded and closed, then any open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ call it $U$ where $X \subset U$, will imply that $X$ is an open set of the subspace topology, so yes you could have an open set which contains all its limit points (hence closed).

Comment: So X is both open and closed?

Comment: @primenumber57 open and closed are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: I know that they are not

Comment: @primenumber57 are you asking me if you know this from $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @primenumber57 so shouldn't that tell you if you could have a neighborhood of a point which is closed?

Comment: I was confused because of the other answer posted by Paul

Comment: I can't use the chat I am sorry

Comment: @primenumber57 Its ok, gd luck.